# How to divide a stream into chunks that can be played with the Media Source API?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, media-source, web-mediarecorder

I'm able to produce chunks of data recorded with the MediaRecorder API. Store them and play them with the MediaSource API.
This works fine, if I append all chunks in the correct order to a sourceBuffer.

```js
async function recordScreen() {
  recordedChunks = []
  stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(getDisplayMediaOptions)
  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)

  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
    if (event.data.size > 0) {
      recordedChunks.push(event.data)
    }
  }
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (isRecording) {
      mediaRecorder.requestData()
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, 1000)
  mediaRecorder.start()
  isRecording = true
}

function replay(chunks) {
  const mediaSource = new MediaSource()
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource)

  mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
    const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer()
    const appendChunk = chunk => chunk.arrayBuffer().then(data => sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data))
    sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', () => {
      if (chunks[i]) {
        appendChunk(chunks[i++])
      } else {
        mediaSource.endOfStream()
      }
    })
    appendChunk(chunks[i++])
  })
}
```

[jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/Buntel/fr4maqtz/1/)

However the problems start when I try to not append all chunks.

- How can I skip the start of my recorded video?
- If a chunk is missing wouldn't it be possible that the video is blank for a second until a new chunk arrives?

I know that the recorded media contains not only raw video data but also some kind of header information. But at this point I have no plan what im doing.
Maybe you guys can help me:

- How can I inspect those header information (non video data)?
- Can I edit or add them? Are there any good resources on how to do that?

My goal is it to just grab any of the recorded chunks and then play the video data in it. And if somehow a chunk is missing it should just continue playing the following chunks.

### Background

I'm trying to develop a live streaming solution which works p2p with webRTC. I know I can put the stream directly into a RtcConnection. But as far as I know this means every peer can share only 1 complete stream to another peer. It would be nice if each peer would be more flexible in contributing to the live stream e.g. sharing 1.5 streams. So I thought it could make sense sharing this data through RtcDataChannels, collect them and play it through the MediaSource API.
If you guys have any other ideas on how to do that, I would be very appreciated.

Comment: "e.g sharing 1.5 streams" what does that mean? Why can't you start multiple RTC connections if you want to share multiple streams? Regarding the Y of your X-Y problem, you might be lucky and only need the first chunk, but I wouldn't bet on that working everywhere forever.

Comment: I need to share 1 complete stream per connection. But what if a peer don't have the capacity to handle another complete one? So I want to split it if possible

Comment: But what does it mean "to split" a stream? Like only half of the video and only frequencies higher than 800Hz in the audio?

Comment: I don't really know. That is part of my problem. My idea was to split the stream into data chunks that I could transmit to the peers and then play them with MediaSource API.

Comment: Let's take a step back, what is the real problem you are facing and trying to solve?

Comment: Did you look at my fidle? I managed to record and play a video from my screen there. The problem is I cant just play only the half of it or it stops playing if I dont add a chunk of data to the sourceBuffer. I want that the video plays the content that is has.

Comment: But this is the Y of your X-Y problem. Once again, as long as the first chunk is there it [might work now](https://jsfiddle.net/d7wfyucz/), but there is nothing stating it should, so it might very well stop working in the future for no reasons (actually it works only in FF). But anyway, it sounds like it won't help you with your unclear "X" problem. This is the one I want you to explain clearly. "To split a stream" doesn't mean anything to me, if I try to make sense of your explanation, all I see is you need to run multiple RTC in parallel. I don't think anything prevents this.

Comment: Your fiddle isn't working at all. I click "request stream" but nothing happens. I think I have to get the raw data of my chunks and inspect and manipulate the meta and header information somehow, that I then put that chunks that I have into a sourceBuffer. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The player is using data from `recordedChunks` array fine because it's a normal video file with headers. Look into segmented video like HLS where you can make TS files and play them from a m3u8 file, which is just a playlist. This is handy because they are easy to distribute and they can be served like normal files over http. A browser won't make TS files but FFMPEG will. HLS is widely supported for playback in browsers. The problem is making the chunks/segments, which each have their own small header-like parts.

Answer (score 2):

> However the problems start when I try to not append all chunks.

You Can't Do That™.

These MediaRecorder streams start with a bunch of header information that's necessary to initiate the decoding in the MediaSource. And they don't repeat that information.

And, that header information isn't nicely lined up with chunks passed to `ondataavailable`.  Sigh.

What's more, compressed video (what you get from getDisplayMedia / MediaRecorder) is made up of key frames and interframes. Without a key frame the interframes make no sense.

It might be possible to parse out the stream to capture the header information. In [Matroska](https://www.matroska.org/technical/elements.html) it's the `EMBL head` element and the `Segment` prologue. Then, you might be able to send just that to MediaSource, followed by the most recent `Cluster` element.  But I don't know anybody who's done that.

And, if you're trying to do a many-to-many session (a so-called "swarm") your clients will each need to send all their data to every other client. That gets bandwidth-prohibitive fast.

[mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org) and other so-called Selective Forwarding Units offer a server-oriented WebRTC solution to this. WebRTC contains all sorts of stuff to get streaming data sources to refresh -- to send key frames on demand.

Comment: "It might be possible to parse out the stream to capture the header information" how can I do that?

Comment: Step one.  Understand Matroska (the video/web boxing format).  Step two: use the [ebml](https://gist.github.com/OllieJones/2fef95b433fc442babdc6627e06085a4) code in your browser to parse the stream and capture what you want. Explaining this is *far* beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer, unless somebody has already created a package to do it. I have not.

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing your own media recorder.  As the chunks are produced you can save them as raw data in e.g., an array.  You can manipulate the chunks as they are produced or just save them to an array and manipulate them when recording is done.  After the recording is done and you have completed any manipulation you can encode the data.

This is sort of the approach taken in this MediaRecorder polyfill when [recording wav audio](https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill/blob/main/wave-encoder/index.js).  The chunks are raw data and not encoded and you can manipulate them as you wish.  The raw chunks are not encoded until the end of recording when "dump" is called.

Yes this is audio data, but the same approach should be applicable to video.